# I need to rewrite Malformed URL to remove everything after .html

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have malformed  URLs like

```
content/abc/na/abc/en_us/find.html/bridge/bridge/bridge/ddc.html?dealerUrl=http://WWW.ssc.NET&modelYearCode=01714
```

I want everything after the first .html to be removed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+?\.html).+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [L,NE,R=301]
```

Trailing `?` will strip query string.